# video tag with nested children

Tags: html, css, video

Is it possible to have a `<video>` tag with nested children? For example:

```
  <video src="../assets/asset1.mp4" controls>
     <div>inner div</div>
  </video>
```

inner div never shows up, nor can be found using Developer tools. What is the workaround?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? I think any element inside the `<video>` element is not rendered in browsers that support it (fallback content).

Comment: and why you want that  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot place content inside of a video tag, if you're trying to put something over the video for some reason, I recommend researching absolute positioning. If you're trying to create something for a fallback, you can set up a script to trigger if the video fails to load.